# How strong consistency-wise is the following large cardinal axiom?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

A cardinal $\kappa$ is called *compactly gargantuan* if there exists some elementary embedding $j: V \to M$ with critical point $\kappa$ from the Von Neumann universe into a transitive inner model $M$ such that $\forall \lambda: \; \lambda < \kappa \implies V_{\kappa_\lambda} \subseteq M \cap \kappa$, where $\kappa_0 = \kappa$, $\kappa_{\beta+1} = \min\{j(\delta): \delta \geq \kappa_\beta \land \delta \neq j(\delta)\}$ and $\kappa_\beta = \sup_{\delta \in \beta} \kappa_\delta$ for limit $\beta$.

Does anybody know, consistency-wise, where they would lie in the large cardinal hierarchy? So far, I have deduced that they are higher in consistency strength than cardinals $\mu$ so that $\mu$ are $\mu$-superstrong.

Comment: what does $\mu$-superstrong mean?

Comment: $\mu$ is $\mu$-superstrong means there is an elementary embedding $j: V \to M$ with critical point $\mu$ and $V_{j^\mu(\mu)} \subseteq M$. Superscripts denote function iteration.

Comment: How is $j^\alpha$ defined for limit $\alpha$?

Comment: The supremum of $j^\beta$ for $\beta < \alpha$.

Comment: What is the background theory you are working in (ZF, ZFC, etc...)?

Comment: Well, it would be impossible to prove the existence of (most) large cardinals in ZFC. Also, when I write $M \cap \kappa$ I mean $M \cap \kappa$. $M \cap V_\kappa$ would cause a contradiction, but I think $M \cap \kappa$ works. Maybe I'm dumb and misformulated it. What I intended by this that $\kappa$ is greater than all the elements of $V_{\kappa_\lambda}$.

Comment: * Although it's impossible to prove the existence of (most) large cardinals in ZFC, I usually just work in ZFC + GCH.